# tinymce-vue in vue2, How can I automatically delete his div when I delete the text in a certain div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I want automatically delete his div when I delete the text in a certain div；
For example, if there is a special area, if any text in this area is deleted, it is considered that this area should be deleted；

automatically delete his div when I delete the text in a certain div；

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.